# How to debug a Node-Red node with VS Code on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, node-red

I'm developing a Node-Red node for i2c devices, but can not debug the code, because it does not stop at breaking points.
Both Node-Red (2.1.3) + Visual Studio Code (v1.61.1) are installed on the same Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit).

I do not want to debug the whole NR system, nor node.js, just only **that** node (.js file) I'm working on inside VSCode and see the errors inside VSCode. *(Not inside a browser's debugger.)*

I've tried many many methods to adjust `launch.json` + `package.json`, added `debugging` lines into the .js file, etc.
I found two configs, which **can start Node-red** without errors, but it never stops anywhere during run.

## package.json :

```json
  "scripts": {
    "inspect": "node --inspect /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js --userDir /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/mcp-pfc-aio",
    "start": "node node_modules/node-red/red.js -v -u . -s settings.js",
    "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=9229 node_modules/node-red/red.js -v -u . -s settings.js"
  },
```

## launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "Run Script: debug MCP3",
            "program": "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js",
            "mode": "debug",
            "cwd": "/home/pi/.node-red/",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            //"runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": ["--preserve-symlinks", "--experimental-modules"],
            "request": "launch"
            //"command": "npm run debug",
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "name": "Launch via NPM",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--preserve-symlinks", "--experimental-modules",
                "run-script",
                "inspect"
            ],
            "program": "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
//            "cwd": "/home/pi/.node-red/",
//            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9229,
            "skipFiles": [
              "<node_internals>/**"
            ]
          }        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally use Visual Code but I think I've got this working.

- I'm assuming you are using the globally installed Node-RED
- I have a directory on the remote pi with the node I'm developing `/home/pi/test`
- In the `/home/pi/.node-red` I ran `npm install /home/pi/test` to install the node. (This will symlink the dev directory into the `node_modules` directory)
- Run the following command to find the location of the Node-RED entry point:

  ```
  $ readlink -f $(which node-red)
  /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
  ```

  This is then used in the next step
- Add the `node-red` entry to the scripts section of the node's `package.json` file:

  ```
  {
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
      "node-red": "node /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js"
    },
    "keywords": [
      "node-red"
    ],
    "node-red": {
      "nodes": {
        "test": "test.js"
      }
    },
    "author": "ben@example.com",
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
  }
  ```
- Set break points where you want them in the node's js file e.g. `test.js`.
- Use the "Debug Script" to launch the `node-red` script from the `package.json`

Comment: Please add the launch.json config to your answer too! Which one did you choose from the 10 config examples starting with `{} Node.js: ...` ?

Comment: I didn't create any launch.json file, I just told Visual Code to "Debug" the `node-red` script (hover  mouse over the `"node-red"` in the package.json and a pop appeared with Run/Debug)

Comment: I have tried everything possible during this 3 month to find out, why does is not stop at any breakpoints. The "mouse hover technique" gave me some new hope in December, but it just starts Node-Red in VSC's Terminal window. The upper Start/Stop signs do not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following setup:

- node-red on a remote server (Linux based)
- A local dev machine, where VSCode is installed.

1. Install Remote SSH extension for VSCode
2. Set up an SSH connection for the user who runs the node-red process on the remote machine. I prefer key based authentication, but it doesn't matter
3. check the connection from VSCode(F1->Debug: Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...)
   [image: connect to host]
4. the extension is clever, and reads the ssh config file. e.g. my `~/.ssh/config` file contains the following lines:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
...
Host hctr-s0-laci
Hostname 192.168.1.2
Port 1234
User la
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/X_ed25519

Host hctr-s0-node-red
Hostname 192.168.1.3
Port 1234
User node-red
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/X_ed25519
...
```

and my VSCode lists the following
[image: ssh confige]

You can see, that I have `node-red` user at my remote server. This user runs the node-red service.

5. you can attach to the node process (F1->Debug:attach to node process) and select the process that is being run buy the node-red user
   [image: attach]
   [image: node process]

In a function node if you insert the `debugger` keyword, the VSCode will stop, and you are free to do the debugging.
[image: debug]

*Note:After the first connection VSCode will install a debugging server on the remote computer. I takes a while.*